# Create texture from hdmi output of other device

Tags: graphics-cards, video-capture

I’m asking for recommended hardware to achieve the following:

I have a computer with HDMI and DVI output. This is a dedicated medical device and I can’t install any additional software on it.

I want to use the video output of this computer as a real-time texture in a 3D application (which I am developing) that runs on another computer. I am looking for hardware that allows HDMI or DVI in, so I can use the video feed in my application. Low latency is very important. The latency of the image being available as a texture on the second computer should be as low as possible (preferably no more than 1 frame behind).

Comment: You don't give enough detail of what you have and what you want.

Comment: I’m asking for hardware recommendations, so I start at 0! The only thing I do have is a medical device outputing an image on hdmi and dvi. I’m asking what hardware I need so that I will end up with the output of that device in the GPU memory of some other computer with lowest possible latency.

Comment: I understand that part, but you don't tell us what the device is or what kind of devices you are looking at.  This site is for specific recommendations, which can not be made if you don't give anyone some idea what you are looking for.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths, they're looking for a low-latency HDMI capture card.  The nature of the video source that provides the HDMI is irrelevant; what matters is the computer they'll be putting the capture card in.  Is it going to be PCIe, Firewire, Thunderbolt, or something else?  (USB is unlikely -- the latency isn't low enough.)

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: @Mark: I can pretty much assemble the computer in a way that suits the task, budget for that is about 15k. I read about GPUDirect supported by Nvidia quadro cards. Is there such a lowlatency capture card that can get the data right into the nvidia card?